# How to add a subfolder in resources in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a project in Maven, and I created a class to read a txt file. The `text.txt` file contains a simple "Hello World" text. When I put the `text.txt` inside the resources folder and execute the code the `text.txt` file is read normally. But if I create a folder within the resources as the name of: `abc`. I'm going to the POM and add:

```
<Project>
[...]
<Build>
     <Resources>
       <Resource>
         <Directory>src/main/resources/</ directory>
         <Includes>
           <Include>abc/</ include>
         </ Includes>
       </ Resource>
     </ Resources>
</ Buil>
[...]
</ Project>
```

And place the `text.txt` file inside the folder: `abc`. NullPointerException is released.

My question is how can I add these sub-descriptions in the POM.

My class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {

        try{ 

            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/text.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String abc = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(abc);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

[maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeZaV.jpg)

```
> Project |-- pom.xml 
>             `-- src
>                   `-- main
>                        `-- resources
>                              `-- abc
>                              |-- text.txt
```

Comment: It is not need to make a supplemental configuration to have a sub directory of `src/main/resources` being taken into account...the whole folder structure under `src/main/resources` is automatically being taken and copied into `target/classes` and in the end being packaged into the resulting jar file..

Comment: @khmarbaise I did the test, and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the subfolder abc to your pom. Since text.txt is in the abc folder, you would access it like this:

`InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/abc/text.txt");`